# Terminal command cd (change directory)

Tags: command-line

In Terminal (Xubuntu) I enter:

```
pwd
```

Terminal reply:

```
/home/mj
```

In the "Ubuntu Documentation: Using The Terminal" it says:

```
To navigate to the previous directory (or back), use "cd -"
```

I enter:

```
cd-
```

Terminal reply:

```
No command 'cd-' found"
```

How do I go back to home directory, using `cd` command?

In the "Ubuntu Documentation: Using The Terminal" it says:

```
To navigate up one directory level, use "cd .."
```

I enter:

```
cd..
```

Terminal reply:

```
cd..: command not found
```

How do I go up one directory level, using `cd` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I can not help myself with this one:

> In the "Ubuntu Documentation: Using The Terminal" it says:
>
> ```
> To navigate to the previous directory (or back), use `cd -`
> ```

As you can read, `cd -` and not `cd-`.

Please count the characters:

- `cd -`  → 4 characters
- `cd-`     → 3 characters

Use the above system for *all your problems*!

### :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need add a space (at least) between a command and their argument(s) or option(s).

You are doing :

```
cd..
```

You need :

```
cd ..
```

Again you are doing :

```
cd-
```

while you need :

```
cd -
```

To go to your home directory you can do :

```
cd ~
```

or simply

```
cd
```